# Read first data of a row and add manually a tag in another column and continue

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like below in python, I want to read each row and at the same time write a tag for it in the in another column, for example I read the first text and manually I write neg in the col tag and so on. can any one help me?

```
      text        tag
1     "bad"       neg
2     "good"
3     "nice"
```

Comment: Why don't you try Microsoft excel?

Comment: now I want to do it in python

Comment: are you using `pandas` dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to create the "tag" column, if it doesn't already exist:

`df["tag"] = ""`

Then go through the lines, print "text" and enter the corresponding tag:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['text'])
    tag = input("Enter the tag:")
    df.iloc[i]["tag"] = tag
```